# What happens to a int i = Integer.parseInt(string) when there are no integers in string?

Tags: java

Right now, I am making a simple tic-tac-toe project. I would like to know what happens to the integer `i` when:

```
string s = "hello"; //or something else, non integer

int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

What will `i` be equal to?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: *"What will i be equal to?"* - What does the javadoc say?  This is a lazy question.

Comment: Are you really doing a project ?

Comment: posting this question here must have cost more time than the research (code it, check javadocs) to find it out yourself

Comment: The best way to find out what happens when you run a particular Java program is to run the particular Java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt("hello")` statement will throw an exception: `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Comment: @Yoram I guess you've misspelt the method Integer.parseInt as Integer.parshInt.

Comment: Thanks @VamshiKrishnaAlladi for the correction. fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the given string does not contain a parseable integer, a 
`NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

For more information, see:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29